# What are the prerequisite for understanding complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, education

Which should I complete first before complex analysis? I am following Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham. Is there any easier book?

Comment: See this post about ["prerequisites" for complex analysis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99484/do-you-need-real-analysis-to-understand-complex-analysis?rq=1)...I think you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Different books will suit different people, most people love Visual Complex Analysis but I didn't get much from it. There are also good free lecture notes you might find online. The advice is: have a rough look over a variety of sources and find one you like to style of the best and suits you best at this time.

It will help to also have understood some real analysis and calculus like the majority of Spivak for example.