# International undergraduate mathematics Olympiad preparation

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, contest-math

I have decided to try out and compete at the next international undergraduate mathematics Olympiad but first I need to get selected for the team that is sent for the competition from my country. I know there maybe many math Olympiads for  undergraduates organized by different countries and I am not aware for which competition I will be attending if I get selected to the team for the moment.

For now all I know is that I have to have a good knowledge in Analysis, Linear algebra, Numerical analysis. My weakness is complex analysis since I have not covered it yet in my degree. So I would like if someone could help to figure out how to start on with complex analysis and maybe recommend some books.

Also if there is anyone out there who have taken part in any undergraduate math Olympiad I would much appreciate if you can provide me some guidance so that I can increase my chances of performing well at the selections and as well as the competition itself if I am selected. Thank you.

Comment: practice questions.

Comment: Related (about *complex analysis*): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/what-is-a-good-complex-analysis-textbook , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250864/books-on-complex-analysis , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368152/what-are-the-prerequisite-for-understanding-complex-analysis , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99484/do-you-need-real-analysis-to-understand-complex-analysis?rq=1 .

Comment: Also don't forget to check: [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com)